# Angular 4 load child route in root outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a standard admin layout, where all main tabs are lazy loaded modules with separate state management. This is all wrapped in `admin` component with sidebar and `router-outlet`. One of my lazy-loaded admin tabs has a special component, which is supposed to open a full-screen preview of a product, occupying `admin` sidebar and navbar with it's own content.

My app router looks something like this:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [

    /// ... some routes

    { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [SignedInGuard], children: [ 

        /// ... some admin child routes

        { path: 'scrapers', loadChildren: '../scrapers/scrapers.module#ScrapersModule'}

        /// ... some admin child routes

    ]}

    /// ... some routes

]
```

And my `scrapers` module routes look like this:

```
export const scrapersRoutes: Routes = [

        { path: '', component: ScrapersListComponent },
        { path: 'single/:version', component: SingleScraperComponent, children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'statistics', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'statistics', component: ScraperStatisticComponent },
            { path: 'targets', component: ScraperTargetsComponent },
        ]},
        { path: 'compare', component: CompareScrapersComponent },
        { path: 'preview', component: ScrapersPreviewComponent }

];
```

My goal is to open `preview` route of the `scrapers` module on the same outlet as `admin`.

My ideas for now:

a) overkill with html/css (very bad idea)

b) create a separate module for `preview`. Sounds resolute, but it hardly depends on `scrapers` lazy-loaded state, so I would not do this

c) load `preview` in a higher hierarchy outlet. If there is a valid way to do it, I would choose this.

Please, share your thoughts. Thanks!